# Blank Fields Copied as #N/A

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am working with an Excel 2003 VBA script that copies the content from worksheets in an external Excel file to worksheets in our own:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strTarget).UsedRange.Value = Workbooks(strFile).Sheets(strSource).UsedRange.Value
```

In a large number of blank cells, this function is posting #N/A instead of the blank values, which causes errors further down in the VBA code. This only occurs on some sheets, while others copy over just fine, sometimes by adding these values in extra rows and other times in extra columns. I have attempted to clear the error with IsNA to no avail:

```
If (IsNA(Workbooks(strFile).Sheets(strSource).UsedRange.Value)) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strTarget).UsedRange.Value = ""
    Else: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strTarget).UsedRange.Value = Workbooks(strFile).Sheets(strSource).UsedRange.Value
```

Is there a simple way to remove these #N/A values during the copy or even clear them after the fact?

Any other advise on how to handle this issue would also be greatly appreicated, as I'm not a VBA dev myself, but simply the lucky soul who got to pick this up when the only person with Excel and VBA experience left our team. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes when the ranges aren't the same size. You should resize appropriately:

```
With Workbooks(strFile).Sheets(strSource).UsedRange
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strTarget).UsedRange.Resize(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
End With
```

It's probably safer to clear the target sheet first using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strTarget).UsedRange.ClearContents
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Rory!